# mpandroidchart, don't draw the line when there is not data for a period of time

Tags: mpandroidchart

[image] 
mpandroidchart, I am reading data from a tool every second and I am drawing that data well, but when I turn off the tool a couple of minutes and again I turn the tool on, the chart draws a consecutive line instead of leaving a space before to start again to draw the values, How can I do that using this library? 
I would like to have something like the second image

Answer (score 1):

I finally got to draw the line Data Set as I needed, 
this library is awesome, it has a bunch of functionalities.

I saw this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mA3-cz8EGWo and then I realized 
I can change the line color between two dots by using .setColor(List colors), so I used a map with key = data set Index and value =  array of colors for that dataset, and then I just changed to transparent color where I needed

```
 Map<Integer, List<Integer>> colorsByDataSet = new HashMap<>();
```

save the color every time you create an entry

```
addNewEntry(x,y,color,1); //1 = dataset1 
if (colorsByDataSet.containsKey(1)) {
      List<Integer> colors = colorsByDataSet.get(1);
      colors.add(color);
      colorsByDataSet.put(1, colors);
} else {
      List<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<>();
      colors.add(color);
      colorsByDataSet.put(1, colors);
}


 //identify the position where you need to change the color and then update the List<Integer> 

   List<Integer> colors = colorsByDataSet.get(1);

  colors.set(colors.size() - 1, Color.TRANSPARENT);
  colorsByDataSet.put(i, colors);

  //set the new colors 
 ((LineDataSet) set).setColors(colorsByDataSet.get(1));
```

this the final result

[image]

if you know about a better way I am open to hear

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do that all you can do is when stop the data you can insert few entries with 0 value on y-axis and when resume chart will start plotting values again but you can see two lines from the last value to zero and from 0 to the next value obtained.

Comment: hey, yes I already tried that, but it didn't look good. The good news is that I managed to get what I wanted by using: .setcolor() for every single lineDataSet. I didn't know we can set the color between two dots. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mA3-cz8EGWo

Comment: Yeah thats a good thing you can set it to transparent and boom.

Answer (score 0):

Solution offered by Natt (using Linedataset.setColors and a List with an array of colors is great, but it has a problem: it doesn´t work if using a Bezier Mode to draw the chart (LineDataSet.Mode.HORIZONTAL_BEZIER or CUBIC). In that case only takes the first element of the array to draw the line:

[image: Bezier]

[image: Linear]